# Multiple jQuery tabs on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get multiple tabs on the same page working without having to change my markup or style.

The problem is that clicking the tab links in one section removes the content from the other sections

I see other questions with the same issue but I can't modify my HTML or CSS

```
// Change tab class and display content
$('.tabs-nav a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('tab-active');
    $('.tabs-stage .tab-content').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});

$('.tabs-nav a:first').trigger('click'); // Default
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yourbudweiser/ajpL2yur/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with the logic.

- You need to add the `.current` class to the targeted tab, not manually call `show()` on it, as the latter will apply an inline style which will not be overriden by removing the `.current` class.
- Use `li:nth-child(1) a` instead of `a:first` to get the first `a` element in each container, not the first in the entire page.
- You need to remove the `.tab-active` class from the `li`, not the `a`.
- Your CSS needs to include the rules to hide/show the tab content in `.tab-content` and `.tab-content.current`.

With those issues addressed, the code works:

```js
$('.tabs-nav a').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let $tabLink = $(e.target);
  let $div_container = $tabLink.closest('.wrap');
  $div_container.find('li').removeClass('tab-active');
  $div_container.find('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  let targetSelector = $tabLink.attr('href');
  $tabLink.parent().addClass('tab-active');
  $(targetSelector).addClass('current');
});

$('.tabs-nav li:nth-child(1) a').trigger('click');
```

```css
.tabs-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs-nav a {
  border-bottom: 5px #a6a6a6 solid;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tabs-nav .tab-active a {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  color: var(--body-color);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.tabs-stage {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  border-top: 5px #a6a6a6 solid;
  clear: both;
  /* margin-bottom: 20px; */ /* removed for this demo to save space */
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="wrap">
  <ul class="tabs-nav">
    <li><a href="#tab11" rel="nofollow">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab12" rel="nofollow">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-stage">
    <div id="tab11" class="tab-content">
      <h3>Tab 1 Content</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="tab12" class="tab-content">
      <h3>Tab 2 Content</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="wrap">
  <ul class="tabs-nav">
    <li><a href="#tab21" rel="nofollow">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab22" rel="nofollow">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-stage">
    <div id="tab21" class="tab-content">
      <h3>Tab 1 Content</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="tab22" class="tab-content">
      <h3>Tab 2 Content</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help